# How to form a URL to query Azure AD group list from management.azure.com

Tags: azure, rest, active-directory, azure-rest-api

I am writing an web app where the user passes a bearer token acquired from login.microsoftonline.com.  The app uses the token to connect to the Azure AD REST API at management.azure.com. The app successfully executes a `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-09-01` request. The response is `{"value":[]}`, indicating no subscriptions. This looks correct to me, because of our specific corporate environment. When I login from the azure CLI, I must use `az login --allow-no-subscriptions` to avoid "no subscriptions found" error messages.

My challenge is that I want to get a list of AD groups from the REST API. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/group/listbyservice) indicates that the URL format is:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/groups?api-version=2019-12-01
```

I do not see how to form a URL with no subscription ID. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: have you seen this?
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer  There is a list all groups in the org I think that is what you are looking for.  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not list the Azure AD groups via Azure REST API(`https://management.azure.com`), Azure REST API is for Azure resources, the api [`Group - List By Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/group/listbyservice) you provided is used to list the groups in API Management service, not AAD groups.

To list AAD groups, your option is to use [`Microsoft Graph - List groups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)(`https://graph.microsoft.com`, *it is Recommended*)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

or [`Azure AD Graph - Get groups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#get-groups--)(`https://graph.windows.net`).

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups?api-version=1.6
```